# Why is turtle.done() saying it has no attribute 'done'?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm using the turtle module. My goal is to keep the window open, and I have heard to use `turtle.done()` to do so. So far, I've always got this error message:

> AttributeError: type object 'Turtle' has no attribute 'done'. Did you mean: 'clone'?

Here is my code.

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle

turtle = Turtle()

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have a variable name the same as a module.  Change the object name from `turtle` to `t`, for example, and it'll work:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2):

`done` is a function in the `turtle` *module*.

By writing `turtle = Turtle()` you overwrote the name `turtle` so that it no longer refers to the module, but to an instance of the class `Turtle` which does in fact not have a method called `done`.

The simplest solution would be to choose a different variable name for the `Turtle` instance.

Answer (score 1):

`done` is a module-level function, not a method on the `Turtle` object.  Import it from the `turtle` module on the same line where you import the `Turtle` class:

```
from turtle import Turtle, done

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.forward(100)

done()
```

or import the entire module as `turtle` (in which case you should not reuse the name `turtle` for one of your own variables):

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```